# Alternating elements from 2 lists SML

Tags: sml

I have been having difficulties with my SML code in the alternating of 2 list elements. I have to create a final list that will take 2 lists of the same size and alternate their elements. An example would be
  `alternate([1,3,5],[2,4,6]) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`
I am not sure where I am going wrong with the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the code I currently have

```
fun alternate2([],y) = []
    | alternate2(a::x,y) = 
    if length listx = length listy then
        if countListx = countListy then (List.nth(listx, countListx)::alternate2(x,y); count(countListx))
        else if countListx <> length listx - 1 then 
            if countListy < countListx then (alternate2(x, a::y); count(countListy))
            else alternate2(x,y)
        else alternate2(x,y)
    else alternate2(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely with pattern matching and recursion without using `length`, `if-then-else` or `=`. Since this exercise is so small, I find it difficult to give a literal hint without giving the answer, so I'll try and solve a similar exercise in a similar way:

Given a function `f : 'a * 'b -> 'c` and two lists, `xs : 'a list` and `ys : 'b list`, I can create a result `'z list` by applying the function `f` to each pair `(x, y)` where each `x` comes from `xs` and each `y` comes from `ys`. If one list is longer than the other, I'm just going to discard excess elements.

```ml
fun zipWith (f, x::xs, y::ys) = f (x, y) :: zipWith (f, xs, ys)
  | zipWith (_, [], []) = [] (* end of both lists *)
  | zipWith (_, xs, []) = [] (* xs is longer, discard it *)
  | zipWIth (_, [], ys) = [] (* ys is longer, discard it *)
```

Since the response in all of the last three cases are the same, I can also write:

```ml
fun zipWith (f, x::xs, y::ys) = f (x, y) :: zipWith (f, xs, ys)
  | zipWith (_, _, _) = [] (* either one or both lists are empty *)
```

Your function `alternate2` behaves quite similar, except the computation at each step isn't `f (x, y)` since naturally you don't have an `f`. Also, each pair of `x` and `y` should not result in a single element in your case of `alternate2`, but rather two elements in succession.

```
- zipWith (op+, [1,2,3], [10,20,30]);
> val it = [11, 22, 33] : int list
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways in which you can do this but I will suggest one which conforms to the type of your function (`'a list * 'a list -> 'a list`) and which also strictly enforces the constraint that the two input lists must be of the same size.

```ml
fun interleave ([],[]) = []
  | interleave (x::xs,y::ys) = x :: y :: interleave (xs,ys);
```

This function works by pattern matching. In the simplest case, it takes two empty lists and returns an empty list. Otherwise it should expect two lists with at least one item in each.

If two lists are passed of different lengths, then a match exception will be raised as the cases `([], y::ys)` and `(x::xs, [])` do not match any of the specified patterns.

This means that the compiler may produce a warning (`warning: Matches are not exhaustive.`) but this is by design.

An explicit exception could also be created, resulting in something like:

```ml
exception DifferentLengthsException;
fun interleave ([],[]) = []
  | interleave (x::xs,y::ys) = x :: y :: interleave (xs,ys)
  | interleave (xs,ys) = raise DifferentLengthsException;
```

If two lists of different lengths were passed to either of these functions an exception would be raised (below is an example stack trace).

```
val x = interleave ([1,3,5,7],[2,4,6]);
val x = 1 :: 2 :: interleave ([3,5,7], [4,6]);
val x = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: interleave ([5,7], [6]);
val x = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: interleave ([7], []);
Exception- Match raised
```

Comment: Alternative ways to handle mismatching lengths, besides an exception: Discard the remaining elements, or add the remaining ends as the tail of the list. Which is better depends on the application, but avoiding exceptional or wrong state is in either case ideal.